# Using recursion to create a path for child elements

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I have a basic category object that has also subcategories in it. This is a simplified version of my object structure:

**Category**

```
int Id

string CategoryName

string Path

Category ParentCategory

List<Category> SubCategories
```

---

```
Computer
     --> Accessories
                 --> Keyboard
                 --> Mouse
     --> Storage
             --> Flash
             --> Micro
```

How can I write a function that creates a path for all the categories?

By path, I mean:

For Keyboard: Computer/Accessories/Keyboard

For Accessories: Computer/Accessories

For Computer: Computer

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such. Furthermore, it won't do you much good if we do your work for you. Try to solve the problem, and if you run into a specific difficulty, then ask the community to help.

Comment: This is not a homework. I am trying to solve it for hours. Objects and the relations could be shown my work complex so I didnt share it and also I have mention that this is simplified version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public String getPath(Category cat)
{
    if (cat.ParentCategory == null) return cat.CategoryName;
    return getPath(cat.ParentCategory) + "/" + cat.CategoryName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// If grand parent category has null parent you can do

public toBreadCrumbs() {

    String out = this.CategoryName;

    for(Category aux = this.ParentCategory;aux != null;) {

        out = aux.CategoryName + ">" + out;

        aux = aux.ParentCategory;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Category cat=ParentCategory;
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(CategoryName);
while (cat != null)
{
  sb.Insert(0,cat.Name+"/");
  cat=cat.ParentCategory;
}

String path=sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would probably do the job, although the stack is not strictly necessary:

```
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            var pathStack = new Stack<Category>();
            var parentCategory = Parent;

            while (parentCategory != null)
            {
                pathStack.Push(parentCategory);
                parentCategory = parentCategory.ParentCategory ;
            }

            return String.Join("/", pathStack.Select(cat => cat.Name));
        }
    }
```